# org-mode : highlight lines in src blocks when exported

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Github has a convenient way to show some lines as highlighted in the code, [like so](https://github.com/arthurnn/minitest-emacs/blob/ffc1b7e3c65e0b9907d54c332499bc172dcfd526/minitest.el#L79-L80).

I'd like to know if there's a way to setup something similar with org-mode code blocks when exporting (in my use case, to HTML), so I can show a longer code block for context yet point the reader quickly towards the lines that were added or modified.

I haven't found anything obvious in the documentation. I don't know where I would start the research to implement this myself.

Can this be done? Has it already been implemented? If not, can I implement this myself? Where would I start?

I have found that org-mode exports to HTML and provides a `.code-highlighted` class, but that seems to be only for the `(ref:xx)` tools: hover over a reference, the corresponding code gets highlighted.

Comment: There is no way without writing some code I think. You probably need to mark up your code block with something that looks like a comment, and then use an org-filter to modify the output with the html markup required for highlighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the coderef label syntax I use a `(hl:line)` pseudo label that gets replaced by an org-export-filter afunction. Referenced lines are wrapped in a `div` with a style attribute:

```el
(defun org-html-hl-line (src backend info)
  (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'html)
    (replace-regexp-in-string
     "\\([^\n]+\\)(hl:line)\n"
     "<div style=\"background-color: rgb(248, 238, 199);\">\\1\n</div>" src)))

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-src-block-functions
             'org-html-hl-line)
```

Note that labels have to be at the end of the line as shown in the following example:

```el
(functionp &rest form)           (hl:line)
```