# Add CSS class or id tag to individual src blocks

Tags: org-export, html, css

I want to style some HTML source block exports differently than others.

Say I want the "Hi" block to have a green background and "Bye" to be red:

```
#+COMMENT: -*- org-html-htmlize-output-type: css -*-

#+begin_src python
print("Hi")
#+end_src

#+begin_src python
print("Bye")
#+end_src
```

The relevent HTML export is,

```html
<div id="content">
<div class="org-src-container">
<pre class="src src-python"><span class="org-keyword">print</span>(<span class="org-string">"Hi"</span>)
</pre>
</div>

<div class="org-src-container">
<pre class="src src-python"><span class="org-keyword">print</span>(<span class="org-string">"Bye"</span>)
</pre>
</div>
</div>
```

Each block corresponds to a `org-src-container` or `src src-python` and there is no way to differentiate them individually via CSS (unless I'm mistaken).

My thought is to assign a class or id tag to an individual block's `div` or `pre`. It seems like `#+ATTR_HTML` might work but the following produces the same output:

```
#+COMMENT: -*- org-html-htmlize-output-type: css -*-

#+ATTR_HTML: :class myclass :id myid
#+begin_src python
print("Hi")
#+end_src

#+begin_src python
print("Bye")
#+end_src
```

How can I add a class or id selector to specific block exports?

**EDIT**

From looking at the Org docs more, it appears that `#+ATTR_HTML` is only for tables and links when used with a source block. Frustratingly, it works exactly how I would like it to for example blocks: [Org mode - change code block background color](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31528/org-mode-change-code-block-background-color?rq=1) I suppose I could use that, except syntax highlighting doesn't seem to apply to example block exports.

I tried advising the `org-html-src-block` to include the desired tags (based off of [Generate different markup for not-tangled code blocks in org-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/44315/generate-different-markup-for-not-tangled-code-blocks-in-org-mode/44539#44539)). Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to pass information to the function (e.g. such as through a new key-value pair within the `#+begin_src` line). The `info` parameter only contains meta-data.

Finally, I tried applying a filter (i.e. regexp replace). This worked for single lines, but I couldn't get it to apply generally, such for multiple lines or to have a generic form. Using the regexp-builder, I could capture the code portion, the CSS tag, and the value with

```
"\\(?1:[^\n]+\\)#\s+\\(?2:[A-Za-z-]+\\):\s+\\(?3:.+\\)"
```

This would correspond to the `print("Hi")`, `background-color`, and `rgb(255, 0, 0)` in

```python
#+begin_src python
print("Hi")  # background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0)
#+end_src
```

This was inspired by: [https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20417/org-mode-highlight-lines-i$|org-export-derived-backend-p](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20417/org-mode-highlight-lines-i$%7Corg-export-derived-backend-p)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the advice method. It's not the `info` parameter you need, but `src-block`. Use the `org-export-read-attribute` to extract the `#ATTR_HTML` contents.

The following advice checks for the `:class` and `:id` keywords in a `#attr_html` line and constructs a div around the source block accordingly.

```lisp
(defun my-org-html-src-block-advice (oldfun src-block contents info)
  "Add class or id CSS tags to html source block output.

Allows class or id tags to be added to a source block using
#attr_html:

    #+ATTR_HTML: :class myclass :id myid
    #+begin_src python
    print(\"Hi\")
    #+end_src
"
  (let* ((old-ret (funcall oldfun src-block contents info))
         (class-tag (org-export-read-attribute :attr_html src-block :class))
         (id-tag (org-export-read-attribute :attr_html src-block :id)))
    (if (or class-tag id-tag)
        (concat
         "<div "
         (if class-tag (format "class=\"%s\" " class-tag))
         (if id-tag (format "id=\"%s\" " id-tag))
         ">"
         old-ret
         "</div>")
      old-ret)))

(advice-add 'org-html-src-block :around #'my-org-html-src-block-advice)
```

When applied to the sample Org file, it produces the output:

```html
<div class="myclass" id="myid" ><div class="org-src-container">
<pre class="src src-python"><span class="org-keyword">print</span>(<span class="org-string">"Hi"</span>)
</pre>
</div></div>

<div class="org-src-container">
<pre class="src src-python"><span class="org-keyword">print</span>(<span class="org-string">"Bye"</span>)
</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Org-mode produces `pre` elements as HTML output for source blocks. This wraps the output `pre` in a `div` and gives the `div` a `class` or an `id` attribute. Is it possible to instead put that `id` attribute on the `pre` tag, avoiding to generate an additional wrapping `div` element?

Comment: I agree this is not ideal.  I think the issue was that I couldn't get access to the specific `pre` tag in order to give it an `id`.   You might be able to do that using `:filter-return` instead of `:around` (for WHERE in `advice-add`), scan for the specific `pre`tag, and modify the return value so that it has an `id`.  It's not clear to me what you could match on, though.  All `pre`tags appear to have the same form, `<pre class="src src-python">`.

Comment: The reason why I asked is, that org-mode started to output a random `id` attribute on the `pre` tags and that is a diff (for VCS) every single time I export to HTML. Not terrible, but also not great either. But perhaps this solves the problem, have not tried yet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37404938/1829329.